# get SQL results of a query

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I've a sample headquarter table

```
id     name         
1      California   
2      Florida City
3      Washington DC
4      Oklahoma
```

Also I've a sample Sales data table

```
id     headquarter_id     Sales       Year
 1          2             2000        2021
 2          3             5000        2021
 3          4             1000        2021
```

My SQL query is

```
select hq.name, st.Year, st.sales from salesTable st
left join headquarters hq on hq.id = st.headquarter_id
```

The results are

```
name              Year      Sales
Florida City      2021      2000
Washington DC     2021      5000
Oklahoma          2021      1000
```

Is there any possibility to get the results like below even though there is no sales record of California in sales table?

```
name              Year      Sales
California        2021      0
Florida City      2021      2000
Washington DC     2021      5000
Oklahoma          2021      1000
```

Comment: left join headquarters to sales..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not getting the result because of the left join. The way you did, it will not match California since it has no data on Sales data table.

Try this one:

```
select 
hq.name,
 st.Year,
case when st.sales is null then 0 else st.sales end as sales
from headquarters hq
left join salesTable st on hq.id = st.headquarter_id
```

Answer (score 0):

@Guilherme Barbosa gave you correct query but let me explain the reason behind it.

> **LEFT JOIN**: It select all records of source/root table on your left and select matching records on right side table. Even if matching
> records not found on right table it'll display all records of left
> side table.

Follow top to bottom table sequence in JOIN as follow. `t1` is coming first so its on left side of query in `ON t1.id = t2.id` and `t2` comes before `t3` so `ON t2.id = t3.id`

```
SELECT *****
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table3 t2
**ON t1.id = t2.id**
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
**ON t2.id = t3.id**
```

Now in your query you are using `salesTable` as source/root table in your query which has only 3 `headquarter_id` and its on left side (LEFT JOIN) of your data selection query. Thus it returns only 3 records.

If you use source/root table `headquarter` in `FROM` clause then its going to select all your headquarter and display records matching in `salesTable`.

Correct query is as follow.

```
SELECT hq.name, st.Year,
    CASE
        WHEN st.sales IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE st.sales
    END AS sales
FROM headquarters hq
LEFT JOIN salesTable st ON
hq.id = st.headquarter_id
```